# NET MAUI Android: ForegroundService not running constantly

Tags: android, maui, foreground-service

I created a simple MAUI app with a foreground service.
I started with a sample found at StackOverflow (How to create an Android foreground service in MAUI).
The service is starting a simple logger writing every 5 seconds a timestamps into a file.

As long as my app is activated the service is running fine.
When the app is deactivated the timestamps are getting more and more rarely, anomalous, sometimes even stop.
When resuming the app the service is running constantly again.

For the logging class I tried two different aproaches

1.) A System.Timer is elapsing every 5 secounds and writing the timestamp

2.) The logger is running a loop in an own thread and sleeps for 5 secounds

Thanks for your comment and help!

Sunny

**Environment**: Visual Studio 2022, .NET 7.0, Android Device API 31

```
[Service]
public partial class LocationService : Service
{
    private SimpleLogger _logger;
    public LocationService()
    {
        _logger = new SimpleLogger();
    }

    public override StartCommandResult OnStartCommand(Intent intent, [GeneratedEnum] StartCommandFlags flags, int startId)
    {
        if (intent.Action == "START_SERVICE")
        {
            var notification = RegisterNotification();
            StartForeground(100, notification);
            _logger.Start();
        }
        else if (intent.Action == "STOP_SERVICE")
        {
            StopForeground(true);
            _logger.Stop(); 
            StopSelfResult(startId);
        }

        return StartCommandResult.NotSticky;
    }

    public partial void Start()
    {
        Intent startService = new Intent(MainActivity.ActivityCurrent, typeof(LocationService));
        startService.SetAction("START_SERVICE");
        MainActivity.ActivityCurrent.StartService(startService);
    }

    public partial void Stop()
    {
        Intent stopIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.ActivityCurrent, this.Class);
        stopIntent.SetAction("STOP_SERVICE");
        MainActivity.ActivityCurrent.StartService(stopIntent);
    }

    private Notification RegisterNotification()
    {
        NotificationChannel channel = new NotificationChannel("ServiceChannel", "ServiceDemo", NotificationImportance.Max);
        NotificationManager manager = (NotificationManager)MainActivity.ActivityCurrent.GetSystemService(Context.NotificationService);
        manager.CreateNotificationChannel(channel);

        Notification notification = new Notification.Builder(this, "ServiceChannel")
           .SetContentTitle("Service Working")
           //.SetSmallIcon(Resource.Drawable.abc_ab_share_pack_mtrl_alpha)
           .SetSmallIcon(Build.VERSION.SdkInt >= BuildVersionCodes.Tiramisu ? Resource.Drawable.abc_action_bar_item_background_material : Resource.Mipmap.appicon)
           .SetOngoing(true)
           .Build();

        return notification;
    }
    public override IBinder OnBind(Intent intent)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

Thanks for your answers! I add the code for the SimpleLogger, hope this helps!

```
    public class SimpleLogger
{
    private const int _periodMsec = 5000;
    private Timer _timer;
    private string _pathFilename;
    public SimpleLogger()
    {
        _pathFilename = Path.Combine(FileSystem.Current.CacheDirectory, "DemoLogging.txt");
    }

    public void Start()
    {
        _timer = new Timer(TimerElapsed, null, 0, _periodMsec);
    }

    public void Stop()
    {
        _timer.Dispose();
        _timer = null;
    }

    private void TimerElapsed(object state)
    {
        var s = DateTime.Now.ToString("G");
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine($"SimpleLogger.TimerElapsed() {s}");

        using (StreamWriter sw = File.AppendText(_pathFilename))
        {
            sw.WriteLine(s);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Google `android foreground service keep alive`. You’ll have to adapt the solutions you see, to c#. Pay attention to mentions of battery life.

Comment: Cloud you provide the code about `SimpleLogger` so that I can reproduce the situation you described?

Comment: @Haimo Did you find a solution to this?  I'm having the exact same issue.

Comment: @Dave  B84: no unfortunately not. I had to do lot of other stuff, but I will deal with the topic again

Comment: I started  a new attempt to solve this issue: See the repository on Github

https://github.com/HaimoHeymann/MauiServiceDemo

I hope someone can suggest a solution, thanks in advance